# How to add a sidebar to Woocommerce Shop Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar, woocommerce-theming

So, I'm making my own theme from scratch for Wordpress with the Woocommerce plugin. I can seem to find how to add a sidebar widget to my Shop page... There is no area for it in thw Widgets menu and I can't seem to find how to create it and edit it...

Can someone help me understant how to create it and which files/code do I need to create in my child theme?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a widget area in your functions.php with this function :

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) 
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class = "widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
);
```

And for display in your theme :

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Sidebar") ) : ?>
```

Comment: Where do I place this code? 
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Sidebar") ) : ?>

Comment: Ok, but that's my problem I don't know in which file... I've placed it in the file woocommerce.php that has the following code:
`<?php get_header(); ?><div id="main" class="row">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Shop Sidebar") ) : ?><div class="col-lg-3"></div><?php endif;?>
        <div id="content" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><?php woocommerce_content(); ?></div></div><?php get_footer(); ?>`
It shows on the Shop Page but before everything else... And **only** in the Shop Page. this way is showing up in the Product Page...

Answer (score 0):

Try this on header.php for example, you can add sidebar where u want

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'Sidebar' ) ) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' );
}
```